# Angular.js custom date filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, angularjs-filter

I am trying to create a filter in Angular.js to check if the date of an item falls between two selected dates. My problem is that I need to use the existing date filter in my filter. My code is shown below, is there a way to inject $filter into my filter?

```
app.filter 'dateFilter', ['input', 'startDate', 'endDate', 'field', '$filter', (input, startDate, endDate, field, $filter) ->
    if startDate or endDate
      filteredItems = []
      if startDate
        filteredItems.push(record) for record in input when $filter('date')(record[field], 'shortDate') >= startDate
      if endDate
        filteredItems.push(record) for record in input when record[field] <= endDate
      filteredItems
    else
      input
]
```

### Update

I was trying to inject $filter incorrectly. Here is the updated code which now works.

```
app.filter 'dateFilter', ['$filter', ($filter) ->
  (input, startDate, endDate, field) ->
    if startDate or endDate
      filteredItems = []
      if startDate
        filteredItems.push(record) for record in input when $filter('date')(record[field], 'shortDate') >= startDate
      if endDate
        filteredItems.push(record) for record in input when $filter('date')(record[field], 'shortDate') <= endDate
      filteredItems
    else
      input
]
```

Comment: That ain't JavaScript. CoffeeScript maybe? You might be missing a tag.

Comment: Yes, it's CoffeeScript, I can post the javascript code if needed.

Comment: It looks like you're already injecting filter ... is this not working?

Comment: No, it is not working, I get an error (Error: [$injector:unpr])

Comment: @Sean are you sure that `input`, `startDate`, `endDate`, and `field` are injectable?

Comment: Yes, I just had the format wrong, I'll post the updated code which seems to work properly now.